# How can I add a legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that includes the goal (money wise) non profits wants to raise, with the column next to it saying the year of their goal, and then next to it how much they actually collected/raised that year

I did the following to sum how the total of goal amounts per year and to sum the total of money actually collected per year:

```
total_goal <- aggregate(x = data$goal,by = list(year), FUN = sum)  
total_collected <- aggregate(x = data$collected, by = list(year), FUN = sum)
```

Now I want to plot this data. I did it like so:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = total_collected, aes(x=Group.1, y=x, group=1)) +
  geom_line(data = total_goal, aes(x = Group.1, y =x, color = "Total  Goal")) +
  geom_line(data = total_collected, aes(x = Group.1, y =x, color = "Total Collected"), linetype="dotted") +
  geom_point(color = "orange") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Total Goal" = "green", "Total Collected" = "orange")) +
  labs(title = "xx") +
  xlab("xx") +
  ylab("xx")
```

As you can see I had to manually add the legend stating:

```
scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", 
                   values = c("Total Goal" = "green", "Total Collected" = "orange"))
```

How can I add this legend without manually writing it like this? So that it derives from the data points itself.

The legend should mark green for Goal and orange for Amount Collected.

Thank you!

Also, maybe there is a simpler way to do this whole plot and i am just over complicating it, any thoughts on a simpler code are welcomed.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(data, 20))` in the question, please? Without data it's difficult to answer. Anyway, to assign the colors orange and green you will have to do it manually, ggplot2's defaults are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created some sample data:

```
total_goal <- data.frame(Group.1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                              x = c(1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2))

total_collected <- data.frame(Group.1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                              x = c(2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1))
```

You can use this code:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = total_collected, aes(x=Group.1, y=x, group=1)) +
  geom_line(data = total_goal, aes(x = Group.1, y =x, color = "Total Goal")) +
  geom_line(data = total_collected, aes(x = Group.1, y =x, color = "Total Collected"), linetype="dotted") +
  geom_point(color = "orange") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", breaks = c("Total Goal", "Total Collected"), 
                     values = c("Total Goal" = "green", "Total Collected" = "orange")) +
  labs(title = "xx") +
  xlab("xx") +
  ylab("xx") 

plot
```

Output plot:

[image]

Comment: This is so so useful! Thank you! I was wondering, what does Group.1 here mean and x? Are those variables we make or that are part of the format of a ggplot code

Comment: Hi @SarahH, I just created a sample data. This means that the values of Group.1 and x makes no sense. Group.1 and x are the variables you used in your code, so that is why I called them too. And yes they are used for the format of a geplot code like the x-axis and y-axis.

Comment: I was also wondering if i want to change the colors to let's say red and blue, what can i do. i tried switching the names on the code from green to blue, orange to red, but it doesnt show

Comment: @SarahH, you should set in `geom_point` the color to "blue" and in the `scale_color_manual` set Total Collected to "blue" and Total Goal to "red".

Comment: I did and for some reason it doesnt change. I wonder what is wrong with my code

Comment: It worked! Silly me. I had a typo. Thank you so much Quinten!